# Seven strange souvenirs

Tags: wordplay, music

Whilst sorting through the junk under my bed,I found these seven strange souvenirs,all of which give a clue to the lyrics of a popular song-just work out which song is referred to in each clue. Simples!

1. **SEASIDE SPECIAL**---

   `Ticket valid **3 FEB** for final departure of the day only.Please be at the platform 10 minutes before train is scheduled to leave. **COMPLIMENTARY TICKET** Admit the Three Persons of the Trinity.Enjoy your seaside special trip!`
2. **NEXT CASE: The State vs The Crackerjack Cereal Company**

   `Petitioner states dental injuries due to presence of foreign object in cereal container-
    **STATUS**:Thrown out-lack of any evidence citing presence of said object.`
3. **Sheffield Junior School  ………………………….Term Summer 1995 Report Card**

   `Breast development.............1/24. Excellent
   Class popularity................1/24. Excellent
   Signed...............................Mr.Martyn`
4. **Harbour Cafe-SPRING SPECIAL**

   `Light snacks:Cake and tea- $2,Main course: Codfish  $5`

   `*We regret to announce that the codfish is currently unavailable,due to the presence of maggots in the butter used for frying*`
5. **OBITUARIES-21/7/1969**

   `In loving memory of Frank(born 1950),died of shrapnel injuries serving his queen and country`
6. **LIST TO DO ON RETURN FROM JUAN-LES-PINS**

   `*Take swimsuit in for cleaning.
   *Pack for St.Moritz
   *Buy brandy-Napoleon
   *Arrange for stabling of the horse at Christmas.
   *Safe deposit for Picasso and college qualifications`
7. **CURRICULUM VITAE**

   `Previous occupations: King, emperor, owner of the city
   Duties: Conquering,making enemies tremble, ruling fearfully`

   `Current occupation: Street sweeper
   Duties: Keeping streets clean`

Answer (score 8):

Another single answer:
7.

> Coldplay - Viva La Vida

Answer (score 6):

**Summing up:**

1

> American Pie by Don McLean

2

> UNKNOWN

3 (per Statman)

> Pulp - Disco 2000

4 (per Walt)

> I's the B'y (as in "I'm the Boy"), a traditional Newfoundland song sung by fishermen

5 (per Walt)

> Redgum's I was only 19

6

> Where Do You Go to My Lovely by Peter Sarstedt

7 (per Reiner)

> Coldplay - Viva La Vida

Answer (score 5):

Just one answer from me:

3

> Pulp - Disco 2000

Answer (score 3):

And 4:

> [*I's the B'y*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27s_the_B%27y) (as in "I'm the Boy"), a traditional Newfoundland song sung by fishermen which includes the lyrics:
>
>  *"Sods and rinds to cover your flake, **cake and tea for supper, codfish in the spring o' the year fried in maggoty butter.**"*

And 5 is actually:

> Redgum's [*I was only 19*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Was_Only_Nineteen), which is based on a true story and contains the lyrics: **"And Frankie kicked a mine the day that mankind kicked the moon"**, which alludes to Apollo 11 landing on the moon on July 20th, 1969 (and since he was 19, he was born in 1950).

And I *might* have an idea about 2...

> This might be a bit of a stretch, but Lorde's song [*Royals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royals_(song)) contains the line:
>
>  ***"I cut my teeth on wedding rings in the movies"***
>
>  Meaning, she learned about diamond rings from watching movies - but the sentence *could* be interepreted differently: Some of the Cracker Jack prizes were toy rings (and inexpensive wedding rings [were mockingly called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracker_Jack#Toys) 'Cracker Jack rings'), and Cracker Jack was available in consession stands in movie theaters... So it could potentially mean that she bit into a ring while watching a movie and cut her tooth. :)

Comment: OK you definitely have 1,3,4,6 and 7 complete... 5 may fit in,but there is one where the lyrics fit exactly. And blame my Canadian housemate for introducing me to Great Big Sea

Comment: @Kit-Ginevra Thanks for saying that, I thought the others were already solved. Still can't recall a song where someone bites down on a Cracker Jack prize, though...

Answer (score 1):

5:

> Nineteen, by Paul Hardcastle

Answer (score 0):

Yet another single answer: on 2 (though I'm not sure of it)

> "Do It Again" by Steely Dan.  ("You go back Jack do it again.")